# concatenating tables in DolphinDB database

Tags: python, concatenation, dolphindb

What is the DolphinDB function for concatenating tables, such as concat() in Python? DolphinDB's SQL join functions are all about merging tables, not concatenating tables.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for *How to do `UNION`s*?

Answer (score 0):

Use function `unionAll` please. Here is the example.

```
t1 = table( 1 2 3 as id, `IBM`MSFT`GOOG as sym)
t2 = table( 4 5 as id, `ORCA`C as sym)
unionAll(t1, t2)
```

If one needs to concatenate multiple tables:

```
t1 = table( 1 2 3 as id, `IBM`MSFT`GOOG as sym)
t2 = table( 4 5 as id, `ORCA`C as sym)
t3 = table(6 7 as id, `BIDU`BABA as sym)
unionAll([t1, t2, t3], false)
```